# Disable a button after clicking using ActionRowBuilder Discord.Js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm facing a strange problem, I can't disable a button after it's been clicked. Actually, the disable option doesn't appear.
For deffing button I use this function

```
const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
    .addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId(
)
            .setLabel('Test 2')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),

        new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('test_2')
            .setLabel('Test 2')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger),
    );
```

I am sending this code as a follow up

```
await interaction.followUp(
            {
                content: `Test`,
                ephemeral: true,
                components: [row],
                fetchReply: true
            }
        );
```

I tried this way too

```
row[0].components[0].setDisabled(true)
```

I also tried with foreach.. and the same thing

Should I specify that I use typescript, is it because of this?

Comment: Do you send this `row` as one of the `components`? Then what happens? What do you do when someone clicks it? It seems you'll need to post some more code here :)

Comment: I updated how I ship.
For example, when someone presses the button (if it is the person who wrote the message), the button should be disabled or deleted
I tried to do several ways as I showed there but without success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive a button interaction, you receive the `ActionRow` as the first component of the message (i.e. `interaction.message.components[0]`). This contains your buttons inside its `component` property.

You could update this row by iterating over this array of buttons and checking if the current `interaction`'s `customId` is the same as the current button's `customId`. If it's the same, you will need to use the `ButtonBuilder.from()` method to update the button (as `Components` received from the API are not directly mutable in v14 of discord.js). Then, you can use `.setDisabled(true)` on this.

Once the button is updated, you can edit the original message and send the now updated `ActionRow`. You can find an example below:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message: Message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const row = new ActionRowBuilder<ButtonBuilder>().addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('test_1')
      .setLabel('Test 1')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),

    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setCustomId('test_2')
      .setLabel('Test 2')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger),
  );

  message.channel.send({ components: [row] });
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction: Interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

  let { customId } = interaction;
  let row = interaction.message.components[0];

  // TS complains about components being read-only without "as any"
  (row.components as any) = row.components.map((button) =>
    button.customId === customId
      ? ButtonBuilder.from(button as APIButtonComponent).setDisabled(true)
      : button,
  );

  await interaction.message.edit({ components: [row] });

  interaction.reply({
    content: `Button with ${customId} is disabled`,
    ephemeral: true,
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: I can't quite manage to change it the way you did

Comment: I use followUP ...

Comment: Error [ChannelNotCached]: Could not find the channel where this message came from in the cache!

Comment: The disabled works but i cant update my component on discord because above error

Comment: Can you upload the content of your file to a site like pastebin.com and post the link here so I could take a look at it? Thanks